# Why python setup.py gave me the 'error: option --install-dir not recognized' error?

Tags: python, setup.py

When I try to install a python project into a custom local python repo, I use the following command:

```
python setup.py install --install-dir /home/peng/python-temp
```

where setup.py is the simple setuptools script of python project Keras:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/setup.py

But this command triggers the following error:

```
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --install-dir not recognized
```

Why the argument in the error prompt doesn't exist? and what should I use that can effectively replace it?

**UPDATE1**

The argument --install-dir is prompted by the following error information triggered by setup.py:

```
python setup.py install
running install

error: can't create or remove files in install directory
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/test-easy-install-13269.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
```

**UPDATE2** I tried the '--prefix' option and this is what I got:

```
python setup.py install --prefix /home/peng/python-temp
running install
Checking .pth file support in /home/peng/python-temp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
/opt/conda3/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /home/peng/python-temp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /home/peng/python-temp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ''

Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

* You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

* You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

* You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations


Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

So none of them works.

Comment: What is in `setup.py`?  Is this distutils or setuptools?

Comment: And what is _a custom local python repo_? Is it a virtual env? A custom installation of python?

Comment: Also please edit to include the command which resulted in the first error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback! already revised.

Comment: Have you read the error message about the path not being on your PYTHONPATH? That's straightforward to fix. Better yet, have you tried the `--user` option?